# Lenovo Docking Station does not charge Lenovo X1 eXtreme

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad

When I connect the dock to my lenovo, everything seems to work (audio, extra display, bluetooth), but it does not charge the laptop! Also, the dock seems to be getting disconnected every now and then, for 1-2 seconds!

If I directly connect the 230W cable to 170W port on the dock, it does charge, which is weird! But in the following scenarios it fails to charge:

- when I connect 230W cable to 230W port (!);
- when I connect 230W cable to the split adapter, and connect its two heads (170W & 135W) appropriately.

Any ideas?

The major issue seems to be frequent disconnections!

---

In "Settings > Privacy > Thunderbolt", I can see that the dock is correctly detected as "Lenovo Thinkpad Thunderbolt 3 Dock", and access is granted.

I tried to update BIOS, but there is no package for Ubuntu on Lenovo website.